# WebDAV / Spring integration?

Tags: spring, webdav

It appears there is built in support in the form of a servlet for tomcat [(see here)](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Tomcat/WebDav), but we use spring heavily in my company.  I haven't been able to find any examples of spring/webDav integration.  More directly, I'd like to use spring to customize the handling of the various WebDAV methods so it wasn't just reading from a filesystem.  I'd like to read from a different data store.  Anyone have any experience or know if this is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible. I was looking for the same thing, couldn't find Spring integration with Apache Jackrabbit or Apache Sling but did find it with Milton, see https://milton.io/documentation/

There you can checkout a maven project and see WebDAV (with Spring) in action.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  Milton is the only project I saw for this as well.